# How to restrict entering of data in Google Form, if Google form is shared Privately

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-forms

I created a Google Form and restricted its sharing as "Private" i.e. only I can access that form.

However, if I use the form link and visit it in incognito mode, then I'm able to view that form and enter data as well which gets stored in a Google spreadsheet.

What I want:
Even if someone gets the form link, they should not be able to view form or enter data since I have restricted the sharing option as "Private".

PS: What I'm looking for is something similar that happens to Google Docs, Spreadsheets, Files and Folders. If the sharing option for them is "Private", and somebody gets their link then they can't access it unless they request permission.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a turn-around solution by embedding the form in a Google sites page using [Iframe] and select the collaborates I need  to view the page ,hoping that no one will view the source and extract the original URL of the form